# mysqli->multi_query INSERT INTO no result

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Basically what I'm trying to do is registering a user via ajax when a user submits a form.

I want my data to be stored in 3 different tables. So here is the code I'm running

```
    $sql_insert = "BEGIN;
                        INSERT INTO $table_name_primary (role, email, verified)
                            VALUES(1, '$email', 0);
                        INSERT INTO $table_name_details (user_id, first_name)
                            VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID(),'$name');
                        INSERT INTO $table_name_log_in (user_id, hash_algo, iteration, pass_salt, pass_hash)
                            VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID(), '$algo', $ite, '$salt', '$hash');
                       COMMIT;";

    $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

    if ($mysqli->multi_query($sql_insert)) {
        do {
            /* store first result set */
            if ($result = $mysqli->store_result()) {
                while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
                    printf("%s\n", $row[0]);
                }
                $result->free();
            }
            /* print divider */
            if ($mysqli->more_results()) {
                printf("-----------------\n");
            }
        } while ($mysqli->next_result());
    }
```

Here the query is executing and there is no error thrown by the server, but no row is added to the database at the end.
What I'm missing?

I would be glad if someone suggest a better approach for this.

Comment: Remove BEGIN and COMMIT,I suspect it treats it as a single query.OR put each query in double quotes,separate them with comma.

Comment: Echo `$sql_insert` and then try running the query directly against the database; this will tell you if the query is valid or not...

Comment: @TiesonT. yes it is running successfully in phpMyAdmin but not here

Comment: @Anuj Same user credentials?

Comment: why dont you use BEGIN ... END than BEGIN ... COMMIT? :S

Comment: @TiesonT. I'm doing this on localhost and not using any pass

Comment: `START TRANSACTION;` at the starting instead of `BEGIN;` did the work for, Thanks everyone for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

You should use set_error_handler() to check the error return from the SQL call. For instance:

```
set_error_handler( "NormalErrorHandler" ) ;

function NormalErrorHandler( $errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline )
    {
    $ErrType = DecodeErrno( $errno ) ;
    $Backtrace = debug_backtrace() ;
    // The first item in debug_backtrace() is this function, so no use printing it
    unset( $Backtrace[ 0 ] ) ;
    $FullError = "Server: {$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']}\nIP: {$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']}\n"
        . "$ErrType: $errstr\nLine: $errline\nFile: $errfile\n"
        . "debug_backtrace():\n" . print_r( $Backtrace, TRUE )
        . "GLOBALS:\n" . print_r( $GLOBALS, TRUE )
        ;
    die( $FullError ) ;
    }
```